# How to setup Python virtual environment with bindings for gstreamer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I would like to use gstreamer library (1.0+) inside my python code. As they mention on [their website](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html) they offer python bindings, but unfortunately they do not provide any additional information on how to get it up and running.

Can someone please provide a step by step instructions on how to install all the required package (preferably with `pip`) in order to use gstreamer inside a python virtual environment. A minimal working example would also be highly appreciated.

ps: I am working on Ububtu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use gstreamer with python bindings a PyGObject package must be installed.
The setup procedure is the following:

1. Open a terminal and enter your virtual environment
2. Execute `sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev gcc libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev gir1.2-gtk-3.0` to install the build dependencies and GTK
3. Execute `pip3 install pycairo` to build and install Pycairo
4. Execute `pip3 install PyGObject` to build and install PyGObject

A more comprehensive guide can be found here:
https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score -1):

Check their examples:

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-python/-/tree/master/examples

Everything to get started should be in there.

Comment: I did follow that. I cloned the repository, created a new virtual env, install the packages from `examples/requiremnts.txt` and the try to run the `examples/helloworld.py` script. The script failed with error message: `AttributeError: module 'gi' has no attribute 'require_version' `

Comment: You need python3-gi, a library to talk with all GObject oriented libraries.